# using thumbnails in multiple modals the previous modal thumbnail shows onto the next modal

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Would really appreciate any help, I can't find any solution and I suck at js

```js
<script>
function myFunction(imgs) {
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";

<!-- I Thought maybe I would have to make a new var for each modal which isn't ideal -->
<!-- But was the only way I could figure out how to get multiple modals working with thumbnails -->

  var expandImg1 = document.getElementById("expandedImg1");
  expandImg1.src = imgs.src;
  expandImg1.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

```html
//Modal 1 dialog 

<img id="expandedImg" style="width:80%" src="img1.jpg">

 <div class="col-md-2 product_img">
 <img src="img1.jpg" style="width:120px" onclick="myFunction(this);">
                                    
 <img src="img2.jpg" style="width:120px" onclick="myFunction(this);">
</div>

//Modal 2 dialog 

<img id="expandedImg1" style="width:80%" src="img1.jpg">

 <div class="col-md-2 product_img">
 <img src="img3.jpg" style="width:120px" onclick="myFunction(this);">
                                    
 <img src="img4.jpg" style="width:120px" onclick="myFunction(this);">
</div>

Feels like it's probably something really dumb I overlooked or don't know yet but any help would be greatly appreciated
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem and sorry I was missing some important code

```
<input type="button" value="Quick View" src="img/jesus.jpg" class="viewbtn btn btn- 
primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product_view7" onclick="myFunction(this);">
```

The problem was I had the used button tag instead of input like shown above